# Is $f \in L^2(M)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $$M=\lbrace rcos(\phi),rsin(\phi)\in \mathbb{R^2}:0<r<1,-\frac{\pi}{2}<\phi<\frac{\pi}{2}\rbrace$$
and $$ f(rcos(\phi),rsin(\phi))=rcos(\phi)$$

I have to show that $$ \int_M|f|^2d\mu <\infty $$ .
My problem here is that f has polarcoordinates as arguments . Can I just consider

$\int_0^1 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}r^2cos(\phi)d\phi dr ?$

Comment: $f$ is measurable and bounded by a certain constant, proving the result. IDK what your integral is. Also $f$ does not have polar coordinates as arguments, that would be something like $f(r,\phi)=\dots$. Your $f$ is actually in cartesian

Comment: thanks for your help .I just wanted to know how to calculate the integral of f over M.

Comment: Oh, yes, your integral is $\int_M f$. But this is not that related to $\int_M |f|^2$.